# Config override for 'Name of your site' in control panel

Tags: expressionengine

In the control panel, there's a setting in Admin > General Configuration for 'Name of your site.'

The value entered here appears in the top right hand corner of the control panel.

Is there a config override to set this value, to save having to type it via the control panel?

Thanks,

Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug that prevents this from working.

However, there is also an add-on which fixes it, if you really need the functionality: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/override_site_name

Answer (score 5):

```
$config['site_label'] = 'My Site Name';
```

In my experience, while this override indeed exists, it is not honored in the control panel. Basically, whatever is in the config file gets overridden by what's in the control panel. Not the way it is supposed to be but ...

See [this bug report](http://expressionengine.com/bug_tracker/bug/15461/) for a workaround and detailed explanations.

Comment: Thanks for this Jerome. I'd forgotten all about this bug with it being 18 months ago! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `$config['site_label'] = 'My Site Name';`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work for this. You'd think it would, but go figure... :)